# Magento UI element based on configuration values

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, system-configuration

I am creating a custom module that adds MassAction in sales_order_grid:

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
             <action name="order_complete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">order_complete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Complete Order(s-ASOFT)</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="completeorder/completeorder/massComplete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Complete Order(s)</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to complete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

I have `system.xml` and `config.xml` and have a field enable which enables/disables the module functionality:

```
<field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
    <label>Module Enable</label>
    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

Now what I need is that above ui_element (MassAction) should be visible only when "enable" config is set to YES, otherwise the MassAction should disappear.

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You can add `ifconfig` attribute to `action` tag like this:

```
<action name="order_complete" ifconfig="sectionId/groupId/enable">
```

Comment: but it gives error : Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Element 'action', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.

Comment: Please try adding ifconfig to block also, not sure why it's not working but it works as well on blocks

Comment: I did try adding it on every line but got the same error.

Comment: this answer is incorrect and misleading.